# Sending email with swiftmailer using the Yii2 extension

Tags: php, yii2, vagrant, swiftmailer, codeception

I'm working on a project where I'd like to test the emails being sent out to users, but so far i got no luck setting it up. I'm using Codeception and running it inside Vagrant. What I'm trying to do now:

```
return \Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
->setFrom($from)
->setTo($to)
->setSubject('Welcome')
->send();
```

I've got a main-local.php, which looks like this:

```
'mailer'=> ['class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
'transport' => [
'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
'host' => 'localhost',
'port' => 1025,
'useFileTransport' => false,
],
```

At first I left out `'useFileTransport' => false`, then I added it before 'transport' and tried moving it inside 'transport', as you can see now, but it's the same. The file/email gets created in the project as .eml file, but no mail is sent. I tried setting up mailcatcher (http://mailcatcher.me/), and actually got that working, but it would be nice if I could just change in the config, instead of using a different method and changing code, and the mail would be sent where I want it. (I also tried with port 1080, so that's not it.)

Any help would be appreciated. If you need more info, please let me know!

**Update:**
I found out that I got a different config file, where I'm actually able to use `'useFileTransport' => false`, and then it won't create the file/email in the project, but still not sending it. I copied the settings shown from main-local.php into this config file, moved `'useFileTransport' => false` up before 'transport', but I'm still looking for a way to send these emails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me a few days, but finally found the problem!

So the problem was the other config i mentioned in the update section. Hidden inside codeception/config/config.php was missing a line

```
'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
        //For email creation in project
        //'useFileTransport' => true,
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => 1025,
            'encryption' => '',
        ],
    ],
```

All i needed was the encryption, which just needs to be empty. Emails are now being sent how they're supposed to, and looking good!

Hope this helps somebody out there, happy testing!

Answer (score 2):

[$useFileTransport](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-mail-basemailer.html#$useFileTransport-detail) is a property of the `yii\swiftmailer\Mailer` class, so it does not belong into `transport` part.

If your mailer is configured like the following, it will try to deliver mails via [SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) to the mail server running on your localhost on port `1025`:

```
'mailer'=> [
    'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
    'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
    'useFileTransport' => false,
    'transport' => [
         'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
         'host' => 'localhost',
         'port' => 1025,
    ],
],
```

This sounds somehow unusual to me as the default port for SMTP is `25`.

Make sure the SMTP server is actually running on that port. E.g. by using the `telnet` command:

```
telnet localhost 1025
```

which should give you something like this:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 your.servername ESMTP Postfix
```

Exit the SMTP session by typing `quit` and hit enter.

You may also check the mailserver log file which is usually located at `/var/log/mail.log`. You can view messages being logged using

```
tail -f /var/log/mail.log
```

while you are trying to send them.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

The reason that i'm using port 1025, is because i'm using mailcatcher, which defaults to port 1025 :)